# Redux Boolean state changes but not rendered in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In app.js, isLogged state changed from false to True when button is pressed, however the component is still rendering No!, instead of Yes! as shown in the conditional operator. I understand that it does not violate the mutability rule as !state is not mutating the state itself. React-redux version: 7.2.0, redux version: 4.0.5

## **actions**

```
export const increment = (nr) => {
    return{
        type: 'INCREMENT',
        payload: nr
    };
};

export const decrement = () => {
    return{
        type: 'DECREMENT'
    };
};

export const signin = () => {
    return{
        type: 'SIGN_IN'
    };
};
```

## **counterReducer**

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + action.payload;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1
        default: //MUST HAVE A DEFAULT STATE **
            return state
    }
}

export default counterReducer;
```

## **loggedReducer**

```
const loggedReducer = (state = false, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SIGN_IN":
            return !state; 
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

export default loggedReducer;
```

## Main Reducer

```
import counterReducer from './counter';
import loggedReducer from './isLogged';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';


const mainReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer, 
    islogged: loggedReducer
})

export default mainReducer;
```

## **Index.JS**

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


const store = createStore(mainReducer,
  window.REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION && window.REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION());

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## **App.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {increment, decrement, signin} from './actions'; 

function App(){

    const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
    const isLogged = useSelector(state=> state.isLogged);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
        <button onClick={()=> dispatch(increment(5))}>+</button> 
        <button onClick={()=> dispatch(decrement())}>-</button> 

        <button onClick={() => dispatch(signin())}>Log in</button>
        <h1>Are you logged in { isLogged ? "Yes!" : "No!"}</h1>
        
      </div>
      
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is it typo? It should be `isLogged` in camel case instead of `islogged` in `combineReducers`.

Comment: @oozywaters thank you so much!